# How to resize image in wordpress from backend? Seems like bug in wordpress

Tags: media, images, media-settings

I'm trying to resize images to smaller sizes using `wordpress admin`. But I have trouble doing it. I have selected an image and opened it for editing.
Original dimensions of my image is `255 × 300`. Whatever number I enter to the first input field in new dimensions section another input field shows
`NaN` (not a number). What is happening?

I have noticed a weird behavior in in this case. When I refresh the current edit page the problem is gone. It is bug in wordpress?

A screen shot of the issue is below:
[image]

Here is the image of console
[image]

Comment: what's the reason to downvote, I'm a noobie.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the issue, please? Downvote was probably due to Narek modifying the question.

Comment: @DanielFonda Please check my updated question.

Comment: There is a console error of not defined, try to find the reference of  'ImageEdit',  cause that is the source of that error

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Wordpress bellow v4.8

Please make sure that wp is up to date.

In some cases it might be a caching issue, so try clearing your cache (or just test in a different browser).

Let me know if that does it.

Comment: My wordpress is up to date. I tried in incognito mode, cleared the browser cache, the issue persists. I even tried in different browser, but no luck.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the console, please? To do so, right click, click on "inspect element" and then press escape on your keyboard. That should open up the inspector console.

Comment: you can see it in my updated answer.

Comment: @Anime can you try disabling all plugins (don't delete them since that would cause you to lose data).. if that doesn't work - can you try switching to a default wordpress theme like https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/ Let me know if that does it.

Comment: It's my new project in which I have no plugin installed, but yes there is different theme.

Comment: I gave it a try, changing theme to 2017 theme but issue persists.